# How I can gets image size (height, width) in blob without <img> tag and new Image()?

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I want to get image size (height, width) in blob Object.
But I don't want to use `img` tag in html and `new Image()` in JavaScript.

How I can get size of image in blob Object without these ways?

Comment: without accessing the image you can't get the width and height. so you must do create new Image()